# Browser(s) Erase(s) Form Data Before User Submits The Form

Tags: javascript, php, page-refresh

I have a website contact form that erases the user's entries before they get a chance to submit the form. Is there a way to programmatically disable the browser refresh on this web page?  Maybe starting from the time the user inputs the first byte of feedback, disable the refresh? I have searched several sites for answers, but I don't see one specific to this question. Most are wanting to see the form data still in the contact form after the Submit button has been clicked. Or they are telling me how to disable the refresh in my specific browser. I need the form data to stay entered until the user clicks Submit and not be erased with every refresh, which seems to happen every 10-15 seconds. To see what is happening, please visit my Contact Us form at www.thecarpenterstribute.com/contact.html. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thank you! In general, I would like to stop the auto-refresh of all pages on my website. It's annoying to me. I can only imagine how much it annoys my visitors. Thanks again! I doubt I am the only one experiencing this issue.

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow. I suggest you read the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Why is the browser refreshing? Your request sounds like the code is battling with itself, which is not good. One part is trying to refresh (for whatever reason) and now you want to implement something to stop the refresh? Isn't the solution to remove the code that does the refresh in the first place?

Comment: Please explain your problem and include enough code to reproduce it. Questions seeking debugging help (“**why isn’t this code working?**”) must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also, don’t spam tags. Only pick tags that are relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is this line:

`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">`

your telling the browser to refresh the page every 30 seconds